# How to configure `lxc` like `openvz`

Tags: openvz, lxc

I was going to fire up a OpenVZ node to test out some software, but it looks like OpenVZ is no longer supported in Ubuntu (deprecated in favor of `lxc`.   It looks like can do more than simply virtualize an entire system, and I'm having trouble finding good documentation that would explain how I can start a virtualized system (using an openvz template or something).  Could someone give me some pointers or direct me to some good documentation?

Answer (score -1):

it is a good document 
http://www.scribd.com/doc/36864274/Create-Lucid-LXC-Container
and you can extract open vz template to make a jail rootfs instead of using debootstrap

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to LXC, but have 2 instances running happily using [these instructions](http://blog.foaa.de/2010/05/lxc-on-debian-squeeze/).

Comment: I'm a little torn about putting in references to information on other websites.....should the data move, nobody would be able to understand your answer.